# ntp is not using servers from /etc/ntp.conf

Tags: linux, ntp

on GCP VM I'm trygin to define custom ntp servers but seems like ntp service is not reading /etc/ntp.conf file. I added 4 servers from ntppool.org
ntpq -pn constantly return the same result (metadata.google)

[image]

systemctl status ntp
[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

problem solved
the default ntp client was chrony and /etc/chrony/chrony.conf is the file I should edit

Comment: Your second and third screenshots show that `ntpd` rather than `chronyd` was in use at the time you asked the question.